# EF Core 3.1 property value returns default field value

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, c#-7.0

I have a class property of enum type LogLevel (using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) being stored in my database and a class field that ins't mapped but stores the enum type value as such:

```cs
class ...
{
        private LogLevel LevelName;
        [Required]
        public int Level { get { return (int)LevelName; } set { LevelName = (LogLevel)Level; } }
}
```

But since the field has to be initialized as default, every time I retrieve the value from the database I get back the default value of 0 for Level even though its really 3 or something. If the value is never being set, How can I initialize the correct default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enums in Entity Framework Core models:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public UserSearchStatus SearchStatus { get; set; }
}
```

with an enum like this.

```
public enum UserSearchStatus
{
    StatusOne = 1,
    StatusTwo = 2
}
```

If you don't want to use a default value, make the property nullable:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public UserSearchStatus? SearchStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I initially tried this approach and switched but I came back around to it